# Web.py styling form buttons

Tags: html, css, web.py

Is there a way to use css with webpy's forms? Currently my code is:

`index = form.Form(form.Button("By Index"))`

This return the default button. How can I modify what it looks like?

Comment: What does it return? Can you edit the post with the HTML?

Comment: As far as I know I can't edit the web.py generated html code, but I can use my own html code. I know how to modify a button in html but I don't know how to use the button i web.py

Comment: Use the browser tools to get the generated HTML code.